# Commerce View oddities?

Tags: commerce

hi I'm trying to create a new Cart view which will simply show Items Total, Cost total and checkout links. I wanted to keep the Default view in place as a fall back, so I cloned it to work on it, but then I noticed my new clone view has a **Save** button attached to the footer* which isn't there on the original. Also the original is labelled as Display **Master**, which I've not sen before and dont believe I have access to create such a type.

The footer is set to **Commerce Line Item: Line item summary**  and investigating all the  options that come with this, none seem to control this Save button.

Can anyone help me out with these two oddities? show some info on the altered screen shots below.

cheers.

[image: Image showing Master and Save] [image: Image showing original Cart View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the summary area handler triggers Views Form (even when there are no actual form elements in the view), which renders the Save button.
Once Views 7.x-3.0-RC2 gets released the following patch: http://drupal.org/node/1256302#comment-4909962 will be committed to Commerce, solving the problem.
So update Views to the latest -dev, apply the Commerce patch, and you should be good.

Answer (score 2):

The master page is always present in a defined View, although it may not be visible.  To toggle its visibility on and off go to the views list page and select the 'Settings' Tab.  Check or uncheck the "Always show Master Display" checkbox.

When you begin a new view and generate the a page or block, the hidden master is also being completed.  It serves as the template for any new pages or blocks you create without cloning.  I keep the master display visible and will use it as the template for views with many alternate displays.

Comment: thanks for the detail, it is very useful. Unfortunately I am unable to tick both of your answers. :(

Comment: Does that make me half ticked off? :}